# MVC Add Record to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

Could somebody please help me add a record to a database?

I have created some base elements, but I'm struggling with the code for the AccountController. I would like for a user to enter the values for Stone and Pound via the form, and on posting add a record to the Weight table along with current Id of the logged in user and current date. Here is what I have so far.

**AddWeightModel**

```
public class AddWeightModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Stone")]
    public Nullable<short> Stone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Pound")]
    public Nullable<short> Pound { get; set; }
}
```

**WebApplication1Entities**

```
public partial class WebApplication1Entities : DbContext
{
    public WebApplication1Entities()
        : base("name=WebApplication1Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Weight> Weights { get; set; }
}
```

**Weight**

```
public partial class Weight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Stone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Pound { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

**_UpdatePartial**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model WebApplication1.Models.AddWeightModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("RecordCard", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contact-form", role = "form" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stone, new { @placeholder = "Stone *", @type = "text" })
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-div-5">
            <label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pound, new { @placeholder = "Pound *", @type = "text" })
            </label>
        </div>             
        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**AccountController**

```
public ActionResult RecordCard()
{
    var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var weightModel = from m in db.Weights where m.UserId == UserId select m;
    return View(weightModel);
}

public ActionResult RecordCard(Weight Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (WebApplication1 db = new WebApplication1())
        {
            Weight weight = new Weight();
            weight.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            weight.Stone = Model.Stone;
            weight.Pound = Model.Pound;
            weight.Date = System.DateTime.Now;

            db.Weights.Add(Model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    return View(Model);
}
```

Please note that _UpdatePartial is called from RecordCard like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_WeightPartial", new AddWeightModel())
```

And also RecordCard receives an IEnumerable list:

```
@model IEnumerable<Shedtember.Models.Weight>
```

I need a list of records from the Weight table depending on logged in user to generate a graph.

Just want to add the record and return to the RecordCard page.

Please help, I'm going insane!

Comment: Does `RecordCard` action decorated with `HttpPost` or `AcceptVerbs` for POST? And Required Nullable fields looking little strange.

Comment: what behavior do you see? Does your method get called?  Can you post your whole controller?

Comment: I'm not surprised things look strange, I've been trying stuff all day.

Comment: The line `db.Weights.Add(Model);` is underlined in red so can't build the project without errors.

Comment: You're going to add `AddWeightModel` while the `Weights` is expecting type `Weight`. You can manually map properties or use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to break this down.

Your compile error at:

```
db.Weights.Add(Model);
```

occurs because `db.Weights.Add()` expects a `Weight`.  You are passing it your model of type `AddWeightModel`.  You need to convert your model back to a `Weight`:

```
Weight weight = new Weight();
weight.UserId = //get your current user's ID
weight.Stone = Model.Stone;
weight.Pount = Model.Pound;
weight.Date = DateTime.UTCNow;

db.Weights.Add(weight);
```

Next, your method

```
public ActionResult RecordCard(AddWeightModel Model)
```

needs to be a POST, so decorate it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RecordCard(AddWeightModel Model)
```

Now in your view you are (very correctly) adding a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.  It doesn't help you unless you validate it:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RecordCard(AddWeightModel Model)
```

Step back, and examine what types you are working with.

Comment: Thank you the redline has disappeared, but how do I store the current UserId and current date?

Comment: I have added the following:


`[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RecordCard(Weight Model)`

The redlines in AccountController have disappeared, but if I post using the form I get the error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Models.Weight', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1`

Comment: your action should still be accepting an AddWeightModel

Comment: Please see the amended post as to what code is now in play, I'm still getting the error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Models.Weight', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1` when positing, please advise as what to modify, thank you for helping.

Comment: again, your action is taking `Weight` now.  It should be accepting an `AddWeightModel`.  Do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: I do, but how do I have multiple models or a single model that contains a list of records and a set of fields?